# Check if user is member of a group via Condition in IAM Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have the following situation: by default, users are allowed to perform `sts:AssumeRole` for all resources/roles. Now, I want to deny `stsAssumeRole` for specific resources/roles **except** if the user accessing `sts:AssumeRole` is member of a specific group, namely the group that allows `sts:AssumeRole` for that specific resource/role.

Is it possible to get this done in AWS IAM policies? Or should I look into other techniques? The reason that I'm looking into adding a condition is due to the explicit deny.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAssumeRoleByDefault",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAssumeRoleForKnownRoles",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::{X}:role/A",
            "arn:aws:iam::{Y}:role/B",
            "arn:aws:iam::{Z}:role/C"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "?": {?}
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should define which groups can assume which roles, and then create policies to that effect and attach them to the groups. Is that something that could work?

Comment: Allowing sts:AssumeRole for all roles seems like the cause of the problem here, and is not the best security practice. I second the suggestion from @arco444. You should explicitly allow specific roles to be assumed rather than allow all roles to be assumed and then selectively deny certain roles - that would have longer-term maintenance consequences as new roles are added and people forget to explicitly deny access to them.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The situation you describe is the situation we already have, however due to automation we were trying to loosen things up and allow everything by default, which indeed is not the best security practice, and to deny access afterwards. I have discussed this internally and we are abandoning the idea. :)

Comment: @Safaci Good call, I think.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this.. I agree with the OP. Restricting by 'is in group' is a pretty fundamental thing isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed to comment, therefore I'll share what AWS Tech Writer Jonathan Quinones had to say to my own version of this issue:

> Based on the provided description it sounds like the calling
> principal, without AssumeRole permission, has been granted AssumeRole
> permission via the role trust policy of a role belonging to the *same
> account* as the calling principal. *This behavior is expected* ...
>
> You can specify the roles you want to Deny AssumeRole for in the
> Resource policy element. If an AWS account has a large number of
> roles, it would be a large effort to list every role and you'd likely
> reach the policy character limit. To address this you can create an
> identity-based policy that works like an allow list for AssumeRole
> using the NotResource policy element, see example policy below.
>
> Note: You should never use the "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "*", and
> "NotResource": elements together. This statement is very dangerous,
> because it allows all actions in AWS on all resources except the
> specified resource.
>
> ```
> {
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",
>   "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Sid": "ExplicitAllow",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
>       "Resource": [
>         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/allowed-role-1",
>         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/allowed-role-2",
>         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/allowed-role-prefix-*"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Sid": "ExplicitDenyUnlistedRoles",
>       "Effect": "Deny",
>       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
>       "NotResource": [
>         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/allowed-role-1",
>         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/allowed-role-2",
>         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/allowed-role-prefix-*"
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

This only you helps part of the way as the denies only apply to the group you attach the policy to. Other groups may still assume undesirable roles if your RBAC schema isn't fool-proof.